# PostgreSQL and Spring fatal error when search by Criteria

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using Criteria to search data from DB. But after many request, I have problems:

```
2016-07-14 17:54:08 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

This is my function appear error:

```
public Page<T> findPageByCriteria(Map<String, Object> criteriaMap, List<String> order, List<String> dir) {
    Integer start = (Integer) criteriaMap.get("start");
    Integer limit = (Integer) criteriaMap.get("limit");

    Criteria criteria = getPageCriteria(criteriaMap, order, dir);

    // Pagination
    List<BaseEntity> elements = null;
    Integer totalCount = null;
    if (start != null && limit != null) {
        totalCount = criteria.list().size();
        criteria.setFirstResult(start);
        criteria.setMaxResults(limit);
        elements = criteria.list();
        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
        projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());
        projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty(order.get(0)));
        criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
        criteria.setFirstResult(0);
        criteria.setMaxResults(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    else {
        elements = criteria.list();

        totalCount = elements.size();
    }
```

When I call this function, it will create 1 connection in DB but other function its not. I dont know why ?

Can you give me advice about it or suggest me some library to avoid this error appear?

I dont think we increase max_connections in config file is good idea. We did not increase it forever.

Thank you ;)

---

UPDATE

This is Hibernate config:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws Exception {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory.setMappingDirectoryLocations(
            new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("/.../../...") });

    return sessionFactory;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(DIALECT));
    properties.put(SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(SHOW_SQL));
    properties.put(FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(FORMAT_SQL));

    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Primary
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(s);
    return hibernateTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Restart your postgresql server and try again, post the results and your hibernate config as well

Comment: @WeareBorg I have restart many times but the result did not change.

Comment: You are apparently not closing your connections properly somewhere.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. I already debug it, only function I post have error. Another function works well :|. But in this function, I only use Criteria, dont open any connection :|